# Sharing Multiple Folders with Samba

Tags: samba

How can I share multiple folders in Samba? If I use multiple `[public]` sections in `smb.conf` only the last one has effect. Then if I try to name each section differently, samba doesn't seem to recognize them as shares.

Comment: Would you mind pasting your smb.conf in your question area ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be better if you won't use multiple [public] sections. For every section put there some other name/description so it will give the user hint what is/might be under that share. For example:

```
[Docs]
  comment = Docs
  path = <path>
  public = no
  writable = yes
  ...

[public]
   path = <path>
   public = yes
   only guest = yes
   writable = yes
   printable = no
   ...
```

Set all needed properties for every share as you would like to. If you want to have all shares public (read/write for everybody) just set under each share section

```
public = yes
```

EDIT: Just noticed that you have already tried to name the sections differently and it did not helped. As warl0ck wrote, post here your smb.conf.

Comment: Ok I tried multiple sections and it worked today. Perhaps I was using some erroneous option yesterday ...

Answer (score 2):

```
[foldername1]
valid users=username1
public = no
writable = yes
browseable =yes
printable = no
create mask = 0755

[foldername2]
valid users=username1
public = no
writable = yes
browseable =yes
printable = no
create mask = 0755
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux.  Please don’t post answers that are just a config file and no explanation.  It would be better if you could provide some explanation of how or why this answers the question.